# How do you get re-elected in the tutorial?

Tags: tropico-5

I followed every instruction the Tutorial told me, and even picked the option to sway the vote in my favor using less than honorable means, and still lost. I was kicked out of the tutorial without completing it.

This seems like...a poor tutorial, if you can literally fail when following every instruction.

What did I do wrong? How can I get re-elected, specifically in the tutorial but also just in general?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which stage of the tutorial you are on.

The earliest part has you getting your own citizen to vote for "break off" from your nations' overlord. In which case you just grow support until you have enough to sway the local population.

For the election as in democracy just keep your population happy and watch the voter trends. Try to fulfill promises and if there are lot of security problem (or any other kinds really) then try to fix it as much as you can.

I can't really give you specific answers without knowing which part of the tutorial you are on.

Comment: The latter is the only "election", and thus what I'm talking about.

Comment: There are various faction on your island such as communist, religious, and etc... Find which one is not happy with you and try to fulfill their needs to get more voters. Be sure that their faction are large otherwise you may not get many voters.

Comment: Yeah, that's usually my problem -- I discover too late that the factions I wasn't sucking up to were significantly larger than I expected, and all the good I was doing for the factions I was helping just wasn't enough.